# confusion between default and downloaded python version?

Tags: python, macos, osx-yosemite

I have 2 versions of python on my mac they are  3.6.4(downloaded one) and 2.7.10(default one) . i want to use pandas on my IDLE3.6. So I tried to install using pip. But pip got installed in the 2.7 site-packages.But the IDLE always open python 3.6.4 and when I say import pandas , it says module not found. Finally my question is how can I install pip also pandas on 3.6.4 from the terminal?

Comment: Set up a proper dev environment with virtualenvs, see e.g. https://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/

Answer (score 0):

Download [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) then run `python3 install get-pip.py`
it'll install pip and then `pip3 install pandas`

Comment: when i do that it says me module not found : no module named pip

Comment: when  I gave the second command . it says can't open file install : no such file or directory . Sorry ! i am just a beginner .

Comment: try `sudo python3 install get-pip.py`

Comment: no, it still throws the same error . i don't know where i going wrong .

Answer (score 0):

This should work to install pandas

```
python3.6 -m pip install pandas
```

Comment: i did this too but the answer is same , module not found .